# Automapper disable IgnoreMap attribute once

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a property in my destination entity with IgnoreMap attribute.

I want to disable only once. I use Automapper list to list mapping.

```
public class TestDto {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

}

public class Test {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Normally, I want to ignore this entities all mapping except one method.
    [IgnoreMap]
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

}

class Program {
    public void MapMethod(List<TestDto> sourceList)
    {
        var content = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
        content.CreateMap<TestDto,Test>();
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(content);
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        //I do not want to ignore UpdateDate entity in here.
        var destinationList = mapper.Map<List<Test>>(sourceList);
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you mean by `disable only once`? Do you want the `ignoreMap` not to be considered after first time? Also if you include some code it will be easier to answer more specifically.

Comment: I mean I want to use this attribute all business logic but only one method, I need to ignore this attribute. I prepare some code blocks to understanding.

Comment: I added code example. In my business logic, I ignore UpdateDate my all entities like that except one method. Because in there I need this date.

Comment: @is_oz Can you use `AfterMap()` and do the assignment manually?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
_mapper.Map<DestType>(result, options => options.AfterMap((s, d) => ((DestType) d).Code = null));
```

---

**Full Example**

```
void Main()
{
    IConfigurationProvider conf = new MapperConfiguration(exp => exp.CreateMap<Src, Dest>());
    IMapper mapper = new Mapper(conf);

    var src = new Src(){
       Id =1,
       Name= "John Doe"
    };

    var result = mapper.Map<Dest>(src, options => options.AfterMap((s, d) => ((Dest) d).Name = null));
    result.Dump();

    var result2 = mapper.Map<List<Dest>>(srcList, options => options.AfterMap((s, d) => ((List<Dest>) d).ForEach(i => i.Name = null)));
    result2.Dump();

}

public class Src 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Dest
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

[image]

---

**Alternatively**

```
void ConfigureMap(IMappingOperationOptions<Src, Dest> opt)
{
    opt.ConfigureMap()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, m => m.Ignore());
};

 var result3 = mapper.Map<List<Dest>>(srcList, ConfigureMap());
 result3.Dump();
```

Comment: How I could use AfterMap for collection mapping. Because my source and destination types are collection.

Comment: var data = mapper.Map<List<Dest>>(items,options => options.AfterMap((s,d) => ((List<Dest>)d).ForEach(i => i.UpdateDate = source.UpdateDate)));

Ok thanks but I couldn't do it again. I want to keep original UpdateDate for each entity only inside this method.

Comment: I also added better solution. Please check. And If you believe that this answer is useful please consider to upvote and/or  mark it as answer ..

Comment: IgnoreMap attribute working well. So my case is not ignorig property in here. I have multiple methods. Only one of them need to keep value, others must ignore. So I added ignore attribute. However, now I need to keep original value in that map.

Comment: ok this is inline mapping which only work for that specific method. What do you mean by I need to keep original value in that map?

Comment: I mean my property 'UpdateDate' was not mapping in my business layer until today. But now, I need to map this property. I cannot change my whole code so I looking for a good and quick solution. I use collection mapping, and 'UpdateDate' always coming null because of IgnoreMap attribute.

Comment: you may look for ConditinalMapping but without knowing details of the context I cannot tell you more